# Windows boot manager error

Tags: windows-7, boot, crash, bootloader

This error occurs every time I attempt to turn on the computer. Is there any was of fixing this without restoring windows and losing data?

[image]

alt image url: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=ee1860e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boot manager or MBR seems to be corrupted.

Insert your Windows installation disk and run the recovery console. Type in the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixBoot
```

This will fix the MBR and the bootmanager.

You may rerun this a second time. It's possible that the first run will not fix the problem.